# Overlaying an image on an object captured by an Android's camera, given the object's Azimuth and Elevation angles

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera

I am trying to write an application to display the path of the sun on a given day, time, and location. I already have the sun location calculations figured out, but what I need is to calculate whether or not the phone's main camera is facing the sun (or where the sun would be on some date and time), and then display an image of the sun on the phone's screen corresponding to where it would be in real life.

What is the best way of doing this? I know it has something to do with transforming the phone's rotation matrix in some way and using the FOV of the phone's camera in some way.

Alternatively, if anybody knows simply how to calculate the azimuth and elevation angles of the phone's main camera, I could (maybe?) figure the rest out from there.

I'm not going to lie I had no idea how to approach this problem, I asked chatGPT and got something like this:

> ```
> fun getScreenCoords(R: FloatArray, azimuth: Double, elevation: Double): Pair<Float, Float> {
> ```

```
    // Convert the azimuth and elevation to radians
    val azimuthRadians = Math.toRadians(azimuth.toDouble())
    val elevationRadians = Math.toRadians(elevation.toDouble())

    // Calculate the vector pointing to the sun in 3D space
    val x = Math.cos(azimuthRadians) * Math.cos(elevationRadians)
    val y = Math.sin(azimuthRadians) * Math.cos(elevationRadians)
    val z = Math.sin(elevationRadians)

    // Create a float array containing the vector coordinates
    val vector = floatArrayOf(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), z.toFloat(), 1.0f)

    // Create a new float array to hold the transformed coordinates
    val transformedVector = FloatArray(4)

    // Multiply the rotation matrix by the vector to transform it to the device coordinate system
    Matrix.multiplyMV(transformedVector, 0, R, 0, vector, 0)

    // Normalize the transformed vector by dividing by its W coordinate
    transformedVector[0] /= transformedVector[3]
    transformedVector[1] /= transformedVector[3]
    transformedVector[2] /= transformedVector[3]

    // Get the screen dimensions
    val displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels

    // Convert the normalized vector coordinates to screen coordinates
    val xScreen = ((transformedVector[0] + 1.0f) / 2.0f * screenWidth)
    val yScreen = ((1.0f - transformedVector[1]) / 2.0f * screenHeight)

    // Return the screen coordinates as a Pair
    return Pair(xScreen, yScreen)
}
```

this sorta functioned in that you could move the phone around and the image would move in a somewhat predictable manner but definitely was still way off.